# Difference of between focal_mean and reduceNeighborhood

Tags: google-earth-engine

My purpose is to use the **5*5 median filter** to fill the vacant values of the image. There are two methods I found:
1.**ee.Image.reduceNeighborhood()**
2.**ee.Image.focal_mean()**
Specifically, I think my correct parameters should be set like this, is this correct?
'''

```
    var neighborImg = img.reduceNeighborhood({
                                  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
                                  kernel: ee.Kernel.square({radius: 2.5, 
                                  units: 'pixels', 
                                  normalize: false}),})
    //the 2.5 is right for 5*5? and the false of normalize is right?
    var neighborImg = img.focal_median(2.5, 'square', 'pixels')
```

I don't understand the difference between these two methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No significant difference. The reducers "`min`, `max`, `mean`, `mode` and `median`" occur so frequently that they often have their own shortcut functions (e.g.: `collection.min`, etc).  There's a little more control in how things get run when you're using the `reduce*` function (e.g.: you can specify optimizations).

But the focal_* functions just eventually call the same code.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I also want to know, for a 5*5 window, is it correct to set the radius to 2.5?

Comment: Yes.  But, if you're using a rectangular kernel, then 2 and 2.5 will produce the same size kernel.